# RegEx for matching digits and one dot with quantifier

Tags: regex

I have a specific pattern I'm trying to get. The pattern I'm looking for is the following: **13 digits with a possible dot for a total of min 3 and max 13 digits (including the dot if present) and ending with "/" and number from 1 to 6.**

for now I have this pattern

```
^(\d*|\d*\.?\d*)\/[1-6]$
```

but this matches 1234/1 or 123456.890123456778/2

but it's not what I need

I tried a few things but I think I missing something

```
^(\d*|\d*\.?\d*){3-13}\/[1-6]$
```

Possible match:

- 1.3/1
- 123456./2
- 123456.890123/3
- 1234567890123/4
- 123/5

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you rephrase and provide some examples for what you need to match? I'm confused by your wording "13 digits with a possible dot for a total of min 3 and max 13 digits (including the dot if present)"

Comment: minimum of 3 to max 13 digits including a dot(".")  so can't be less the 3 digits and cannot exceed 13 digits in all followed by /1 to 6. hope this helps

Comment: Why it should not match `1234/1` ? Has 3-13 digits before `/` and 1-6 digits after. I came up with pattern [`^\b(?=[\d.]{3,13}\/)\d+\.?\d*\/\d{1,6}$`](https://regex101.com/r/xwWQdd/1) but this matches eg `1234/1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your wordings are a little confusing but if I got you correct then you can use this regex,

```
^(?=.{5,15}$)\d+\.?\d*\/[1-6]$
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` - Start of string
- `(?=.{5,15}$)` - This positive look ahead ensures that the minimum length is 5 and max length is 15 (adding two for last slash and number)
- `\d+\.?\d*` - Starts capturing the text with one or more digits followed by optional dot `.` and further more zero or more digits
- `\/[1-6]` - Matches a slash and one to six digit
- `$` - End of string

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uDg4am/1/)**

Let me know if this works fine for you else list the case for which it doesn't work.

Comment: perfect thanks this seems to work I modified it slightly to ma situation so here was my final solution based on yours ^(?=.{3,15}$)\d*\.?\d*\/[1-6]$